# Multistage dockerfile COPY failed

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Dockerfile:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11 as builder
COPY server-1.0.0.jar application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11
COPY –-from=builder dependencies/ ./
COPY –-from=builder spring-boot-loader/ ./
COPY –-from=builder snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY –-from=builder application/ ./
...
```

Results in:

```
Step 5/14 : COPY –-from=builder dependencies/ ./

COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat –-from=builder: file does not exist
```

Note that running `java -Djarmode=layertools -jar server-1.0.0.jar extract` creates the `dependencies` folder.

Tutorial [source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-docker-images#3-creating-the-docker-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied the docker code from another site and it seems it contained an invalid dash unicode char: [\u2013](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)

So instead of `COPY –-from` it should be `COPY --from`